# Android how to change locale ONLY specifics Activities/Fragments

Tags: java, android, locale

I know this kind of problems had been discussed various times before but I still can not find a solution to my specific case. Let's say I want to change the locale for my text resources only in specific UI elements through a "Change Locale" button. Here is my approach:
When user clicks the button, I update the each elements that needed translated. The code how I do it:

```
public Resources getResourcesByLocale(Context context, String languageCode) {
    if (context == null || languageCode.isEmpty()) return null;
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    String[] languageCountry = languageCode.split("-");
    int size = languageCountry.length;
    if (size < 2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "language and country is not correct in local" + size);
        return null;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "value of langauge " + languageCountry[0] + " value of country :  " + languageCountry[1]);
        String language = languageCountry[0];
        String country = languageCountry[1];
        configuration.setLocale(new Locale(language));

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration).getResources();
    }
}
```

This code calls whenever I need update my text views:

```
public void updateTextByLocale(Context context, String languageCode, TextView tv, int resId) {
    tv.setText(getResourcesByLocale(context, languageCode).getString(resId));
}
```

However, my application crashes with the exception

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
> #0x7f0e0074

My string resources have the value for both US and KR language. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Layout
To create an alias to an existing layout, use the  element, wrapped in a . For example:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <merge>
                 <include layout="@layout/main_ltr"/>
         </merge>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is going to me with my problem.